# Swift Firebase - get current user with document UID to populate list

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have done this on my android app (and it works), to populate a list with the document names from a collection

```
  db.collection("usersAuth/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!}/KitLists")
            .addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { value, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Listen failed.", e)
            return@EventListener
        }

        for (document in value.documents) {
            val data = document

            val kitName = data.id

            firstKitList.add(kitName)

        }

        mainListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

I am trying to do the same on my iOS version but I don't know whats wrong

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    setListener()

}

func setListener() {

    db.collection("usersAuth/\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser))/KitLists")
        .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error ) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let kitListName = data["KitLists"] as? String


                 let newLists = KitList(kitListName: kitListName!)
                    self.lists.append(newLists)
                }


                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }

}
```

any ideas? Thanks

**-- EDIT**

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlLFP.png)

[Firestore2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRQ2d.png)

Comment: Do you need to append the uid to the end of currentUser? `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`

Comment: I need to know which user I am at so it loads the proper content. And how to get the kitListName. Because on android I just had to do data.id

Comment: is `KitLists` a document inside collection `usersAuth`?

Comment: Try printing your `"usersAuth/\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser))/KitLists"` string to the console, to see if it is formatting how you expected.  On my firebase project I use the userId as the document reference, so I need `currentUser.uid`

Comment: Yes. Check my updated post. There is a screenshot of my Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `uid` from the `currentUser`, for example:

```
if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid {
        db.collection("usersAuth").document(userId).collection("KitLists")
            .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error ) in
        //...
    }
```

**To get the KitLists documentId**

```
for document in snap.documents {
    let documentName = document.documentID // <--- This
    let newLists = KitList(kitListName: documentName)
    self.lists.append(newLists)
}
```

Comment: that part is clarified regarding the user ID. Now the problem is to get the Name of each document like I did on android :/

Comment: also, that userID won't work because thats not a string literal

Comment: I think you are after the documentID for each KitLists document - I have updated my answer

Comment: my problem really was the documentID part and not the path to the collection thanks